# Call find query after saving a array of contacts in nodejs mongodb applicaiton

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, find

In the following post request, I have to save a list of contacts once save is completed find query has to be fired

```
router.route('/uploadContacts')
    .post(function(req,res){
        for(var i = 0; i < req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts.length; i++) {
            contactNumberList.push(req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts[i].PhNo)

        }
        
        //find and save the contact details

        ProfileDetails.findOne({ 'PhNo' : {$in:contactNumberList}} ,
                function(err, profileDetail) {
                    req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts.find(
                        function(contact){
                            if(profileDetail&&profileDetail.PhNo&&contact&&contact.PhNo){
                                if(profileDetail.PhNo==contact.PhNo){
                                    var contactsDetails = new contacts();
                                    contactsDetails.PhNo=contact.PhNo
                                    contactsDetails.RegStatus=profileDetail.Reg_Status
                                    contactsDetails.profileId=profileDetail.Profile_Id
                                    contactsDetails.PhoneBookName=contact.Name
                                    contactsDetails.updatedByProfileId=req.body.vishReqHeader.AppId
                                    contactsDetails.save(function(err,result){
                                        logger.info("contacts saved");
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                var contactsDetails = new contacts();
                                contactsDetails.PhNo=contact.PhNo
                                contactsDetails.RegStatus=0
                                contactsDetails.PhoneBookName=contact.Name
                                contactsDetails.updatedByProfileId=req.body.vishReqHeader.AppId
                                contactsDetails.save(function(err,result){
                                    logger.info("inside else");
                                    logger.info("contacts saved");
                                })
                            }



                        })



                });

        
        //once after save this part has to be fired to send the response
        contacts.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    $lookup:
                        {
                            from: "ProfileDetails",
                            localField: "PhNo",
                            foreignField: "PhNo",
                            as: "Profile_Details"
                        }
                },
                {$match:{
                    $and: [
                        {PhNo: {$in: contactNumberList}}
                    ]
                }}
            ],
            function (err, result) {

                if(result){
                    res.send({
                        "result": {
                            "vishResHeader": {
                                "ReqNo": req.body.vishReqHeader.reqNo,
                                "ProcStatus": 0,
                                "ErrCode": 0,
                                "ErrMsgUsr": ""
                            },
                            "vishResBody": {
                                "Contacts": result
                            },
                            "vishResTrailer": {
                                "Authentication": ""
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
   

            })


    });
```

But before the save quire completes the query is fired and returns a incorrect response not sure how to wait until the save operation is completed and later to fire the find query

**Note**: find query has to be fired only after save

please suggest a way to accomplish it

Request body for reference

```
{
    "vishReqHeader": {
        "ClientId": "0",
        "AppId": "100",
        "ApiCode": "1007",
        "ReqNo": "123456789"
    },
    "vishReqBody": {
        "RegPhNo": "9880889660",
        "Cnt": "3",
        "Contacts": [{
                "PhNo": "7777777777",
                "Name": "Alex"
            },
            {
                "PhNo": "9999999999",
                "Name": "Cindy"
            },
            {
                "PhNo": "8888888888",
                "Name": "Rob"
            }
        ]

    },
    "vishReqTrailer": {
        "DeviceData": "lat=12.9677992|lng=77.596204|IMEI=1234567890|appVer=3.0.1|OS=ANDROID|SoftVer=6.0.1",
        "Authentication": "securitytoken"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **q** or **async** package. Which helps your nodejs code to run serially. 
I have implemented with **q**, I hope you can relate with this :

```
var InsertUser = function(fname, lname, email, password){
var deferred = q.defer();

var user = new Users();
user.email = email;
user.password = password;
user.emailVerified = false;
user.fname = fname;
user.lname = lname;
user.createdDate = new Date();
user.updatedDate = new Date();

user.save(function(new_user_err, new_user){
    if(new_user_err){
        deferred.reject(new_user_err);
    }else{
        deferred.resolve(new_user);
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
}
```

And routes to call this function :

```
router.post('/RegisterUser', function(req, res){
var email = req.body.email;
var fname = req.body.fname;
var lname = req.body.lname;
var password = req.body.password;

InsertUser(fname, lname, email, password).then(function(user_data){

    console.log(user_data);
    console.log("User registered successfully");
    res.json({result : 1})

}, function(user_error){

    console.log(user_error);
    res.json({ error : user_error });

});

});
```

So you can do the same wit your code. Make a separate function for *ProfileDetails.findOne* and *save()* which returns a promise and then fire query *contacts.aggregate()*

Answer (score 0):

Since functions you call are asynchronous, you should call contacts.aggregate inside save for both cases to make sure fired after saving:

```
contactsDetails.save(function(err,result){
    logger.info("contacts saved");
    contacts.aggregate ....
})
```

Comment: that will not work please see in the save query we have if and else both  inside findOne the request might get inputs for both the condition and i will get Can't set headers after they are sent. (i tried this before)

Comment: Why dont you call save function after if - else block

Comment: if i do so either the contact which satisfies if or else is working not both with same error  please see the query section i have edited

Comment: For your first comment, are you sure "Can't set headers after they are sent" error to be get  because you would call 'res.send' only once in if block or else block.